# illegal hardware instruction Import tensorflow. Macbook M1

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow, avx, apple-m1

I am trying to run Tensorflow on MacBook M1 OSx 11.1
when importing tensorflow and launching the .py I get the following error message

```
zsh: illegal hardware instruction.
```

I have seen other comments and this problem appeared on older computers that do not support AVX instructions.

I understand that the M1 microprocessor supports this type of instructions, but could someone confirm it to me?

Comment: I remember reading how GPU support is close to non-existent on the new M1s. It makes sense for tensorflow to be imcompatible on those for now.

Comment: The real question is whether Apple's x86 emulation software supports AVX.  It would makes sense for the answer to be no because the AArch64 hardware SIMD is only 128-bit wide.  AVX is an x88 instruction-set extension so of course it isn't *directly* supported by an AArch64 CPU.

Comment: Presumably you should use a native AArch64 build of Tensorflow, instead of making software emulate an x86.

Comment: Looks like Tensorflow doesn't support M1. Please take a look at similar issue https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/46178#issuecomment-754813954